# Get directory with or without trailing slash of a URL?

Tags: javascript, url, substring

Here's my current code:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var str = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
var subid = str.replace("/", "");
```

When I go to `http://example.com/12345/`, then `subid` equals `12345`.

But when I go to `http://example.com/12345`, then `subid` is blank.

How can I make this work with or without the trailing slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a benefit of inbuilt function [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```
(new URL('http://example.com/12345/')).pathname.replace(/\//g,'') // output 12345
(new URL('http://example.com/12345')).pathname.replace(/\//g,'') // output 12345
```

> The one who are looking for the last segment only can use this
>   function

```
var allPartsOfURL = 'http://example.com/12345/12/98/567'.split('/');
// handle potential trailing slash
var lastSegment = allPartsOfURL.pop() || allPartsOfURL.pop();  


console.log(lastSegment);
```

> For old browsers

```
// create an anchor tag 
const url = document.createElement('a');
// set the href attribute and then use the `pathname`
url.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/12345/');
url.pathname.replace(/\//g,''); // output 12345

url.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/12345');
url.pathname.replace(/\//g,''); // output 12345
```

Comment: it fails when there is `/x/y/z`

Comment: @diEcho I suggested based on his requirement. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: This is not supported by IE. Just so you know. https://www.caniuse.com/#search=Url

Comment: @Nate thanks for letting me know, updated the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider regex,

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var subid = loc.match(/^http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/([a-zA-Z-_]+).*$/)[1];
```

Test with different cases

```
var url1 = "http://google.com/abc-1";
var url2 = "http://google.com/abc-2/";
var subid1 = url1.match(/^http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/([a-zA-Z-_]+).*$/)[1];
var subid2 = url2.match(/^http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/([a-zA-Z-_]+).*$/)[1];
console.log(subid1);
console.log(subid2);
```

Comment: `pathname` is not a full URL with scheme and domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
    var loc="http://example.com/12340/";
    if((loc.length-1)==loc.lastIndexOf('/'))
    {

        var newloc=loc.substring(0,loc.length-1);
        var subid=newloc.substring((newloc.lastIndexOf('/')+1),newloc.length);
    }
    else
    {
        var subid=loc.substring((loc.lastIndexOf('/')+1),loc.length);
    }
    console.log("sub is "+subid);
```

Answer (score 0):

So much overkill and code that doesn't work in older browsers in other answers. It's as simple as this:

```
var subid = location.pathname.match(/^\/([^\/]*)/)[1];
```

You can assign the result of `match` to another variable and add more groupings to the regex if you need to capture other segments, too.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to extract last part of string then you can use

```
loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/')).replace('/','');
```

in case of last '/ first check with `.endsWith('/')` method and then remove last '/' using

```
if(loc.endsWith('/')) {
   loc.substring( -1, loc.lastIndexOf('/')).replace('/','');
}
```

alternative way is

```
 loc.split('/').filter( path => !path).pop();
```

Comment: That will then break it in the opposite way.  Now when you go to `http://example.com/12345/`, then `subid` is blank.

Comment: so always first trim the last `/` and then apply

Comment: How do I do that?